# How can I do horizontal Menu C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

I have spent many hours looking to make a horizontal menu like this:

[image]
or this:

[image]

or:
[image]

Maybe I have to import some third party control. If this is true , is there any free or open source ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [Toolstrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e58c44b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), should be in your standard Toolbox under Menus & Toolbars

Comment: you right! . I   was looking bad . I am using the keyword "Horizontal menu" and for it i didnt find the answer.

Thank you very much.